# Scaling an iterative, bitwise algorithm to solve the Towers of Hanoi using X discs and Y towers

Tags: algorithm, stack, iteration, towers-of-hanoi

I like the algorithm mentioned in this question: "How does this work? Weird Towers of Hanoi Solution"
[How does this work? Weird Towers of Hanoi Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209860/how-does-this-work-weird-towers-of-hanoi-solution)

Is there any way to scale that non-recursive solution of Towers of Hanoi to use X disks and Y towers, with towers represented as stacks?

Comment: Doubt it. How do you even solve the Towers of Hanoi with X disks and Y towers? As far as I know, there is no proven algorithm that solves this with a minimum number of moves. Unless maybe you don't care about the number of moves being minimum?

Comment: @IVlad: if you don't care about the number of moves being minimum, ignore all but 3 of the poles. Job done :-)

Comment: @Steve Jessop - true :). @Robb - your best start is probably the Frame-Stewart algorithm described here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi - It's not known if the algorithm is truly optimal, but it most likely is. I don't know how exactly it can be adapted into a non-recursive solution that prints each move, but someone else will probably figure it out and hopefully post their findings :).

Comment: It is easy enough to solve for X discs, you just have to know if it is even or odd. Y towers is the tricky bit.

Comment: The "optimal" solution is not known for > 3 disks [though the frame stewart conjecture gives some hint as to how to solve it] and the bit solution exploits assumptions in the 3-case.

Comment: @Foo The optimal solution is not known for > 3 PEGS, not disks, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

An iterative solution for the tower of Hanoi with Y=3 Towers and X discs and  can be found on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Towers_of_hanoi#Iterative_solution):

**For an even number of disks:**

- make the legal move between pegs A and B
- make the legal move between pegs A and C
- make the legal move between pegs B and C
  repeat until complete

**For an odd number of disks:**

- make the legal move between pegs A and C
- make the legal move between pegs A and B
- make the legal move between pegs B and C
  repeat until complete

In each case, a total of 2^X-1 moves are made. **The number of moves with this algorithm is only [minimal for Y=3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Logical_analysis_of_the_recursive_solution).**

This solution ignores the other towers, so it works with any Y >= 3 and any X.

> Although the three-peg version has a
>   simple recursive solution as outlined
>   above, the optimal solution for the
>   Tower of Hanoi problem with four pegs
>   (called Reve's puzzle), let alone more
>   pegs, is still an open problem. This
>   is a good example of how a simple,
>   solvable problem can be made
>   dramatically more difficult by
>   slightly loosening one of the problem
>   constraints.

Quoted from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Four_pegs_and_beyond).