# How does this iterative Tower of Hanoi work? C

Tags: c, iteration, towers-of-hanoi

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How does this work? Weird Towers of Hanoi Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209860/how-does-this-work-weird-towers-of-hanoi-solution)

While surfing Google, i found this interesting solution to Tower Of Hanoi which doesn't even use stack as data structure.

Can anybody explain me in brief, what is it actually doing?

Are this solution really acceptable?

**Code**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int n, x;
   printf("How many disks?\n");
   scanf("%d", &n);
   printf("\n");
   for (x=1; x < (1 << n); x++)
      printf("move from tower %i to tower %i.\n",
         (x&x-1)%3, ((x|x-1)+1)%3);
return 0;
}
```

**Update: What is the hard-coded number 3 doing in here?**

Comment: It is using the standard 3 rods.

Comment: Does it report the correct sequence of moves?  If so, it works, and there's no reason why it shouldn't be acceptable.  However, you need to understand it before offering it as a solution to your homework, or you will be in trouble if you are called on to explain it, as you might very well be since it is so different from normal.

Comment: It is not my homework. I just accidently found this algorithm and thought to ask how does it actually work.

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209860/how-does-this-work-weird-towers-of-hanoi-solution

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Might be easier to see in  PSEUDOCODE:

```
GET NUMBER OF DISKS AS n
WHILE x BETWEEN 1 INCLUSIVE AND 1 LEFT-SHIFTED BY n BITS
    SUBTRACT 1 FROM n, DIVIDE BY 3 AND TAKE THE REMAINDER AS A
    OR x WITH x-1, ADD 1 TO THAT, DIVIDE BY 3 AND TAKE THE REMAINDER AS B
    PRINT "MOVE FROM TOWER " A " TO TOWER " B
    ADD 1 TO x
```

1 LEFT SHIFTED BY n BITS is basically 2 to the power of n, 16 in the case of 4 disks.

[If you walk through this sequence manually, you should see the progression of movement of the disks. http://library.ust.hk/images/highlights/Tower_of_Hanoi_4.gif](http://library.ust.hk/images/highlights/Tower_of_Hanoi_4.gif)

Comment: Thanks Harvey, this pseudocode is indeed easy to understand :). Great answer !

Comment: Uh, "BETWEEN 1 AND n" is not at all the same as "for (x=1; x < (1 << n); x++)"

Comment: Just a note: the link at the end is broken.

Answer (score 6):

It is one of the binary solutions to Tower of Hanoi, there is a detailed explanation of this algorithm on Wikipedia - read [the "Binary solution" paragraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Binary_solution).