# Tower of Hanoi Haskell

Tags: haskell, iteration, towers-of-hanoi

I have found the following code for solving the Towers of Hanoi. The code is working fine! 
But I cannot understand what's going on exactly.

```
import Data.Bits    
hanoi :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]
hanoi n = map (\x -> ((x .&. (x-1)) `mod` 3, ((x .|. (x-1)) + 1) `mod` 3)) [1..shift 1 n]
main = print $ hanoi 5
```

Can anybody explain this code? Thanks

Comment: You want us to explain Haskell syntax of this function, Towers of Hanoi solution or both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will assume if you understand the general algorithm of solving Towers of Hanoi problem.

What goes on in your code, line by line:

1. `import Data.Bits` we are importing bit-manipulation functions, the ones we will use in our case are `.&.`, `.|.` and `shift`.
2. `hanoi :: Int -> [(Int, Int)]` the function takes one argument (number of discs) and returns a list of pairs representing moves (format: `(from, to)`).
3. `hanoi n = map ...` . We are mapping this a function over this list `[1..shift 1 n]`, which stores subsequent left bit shifts (`1 << n`) from `1` to `n`.
   3a. The mapping function (`(\x -> ((x .&. (x-1))`mod`3, ((x .|. (x-1)) + 1)`mod`3))`) returns, for a given argument, a pair of `(x .&. (x-1))`mod`3` and `((x .|. (x-1)) + 1)`mod`3)`, (in `(from, to)` format). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209860/how-does-this-work-weird-towers-of-hanoi-solution) is an explanation of why the function works that way.
4. `main = print $ hanoi 5` print the result in a `main` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments ! Yes I am understanding the algorithm, but I need to understand Haskell.

Comment: That's what I explained in my answer, hope it's clear.

Comment: Can you try to give me a more easier answer ?, I don´t understand the binary calculation.