# Using Bitwise Operators in C

Tags: c

I am a beginner to C language.I have a code for towers of hanoi but can someone explain me what are these bitwise operators doing ie if value of i is 1 what will be the source and target output value ?

```
source = (i & i-1) % 3;
target = ((i | i-1) + 1) % 3;
```

Comment: do you understand what bitwise operators do, and just want to know what they are used for in this case, or do you want an explanation of bitwise operators?

Comment: i have some knowledge on bitwise operators but couldn't understand in this case.Yes i want explanation on working of bitwise operators in this case.

Answer (score 1):

`i & i-1` turns off the lowest set bit in `i` (if there are any set). For example, consider `i`=200:

- 200 in binary is 1100 1000. (The space is inserted for visual convenience.)
- To subtract one, the zeros cause us to “borrow” from the next position until we reach a one, producing 1100 0111. Note that, working from the right, all the zeros became ones, and the first one became a zero.
- The `&` produces the bits that are set in both operands. Since `i-1` changed all the bits up to the first one, those bits are clear in the `&`—none of the changed bits are the same in both `i` and `i-1`, so none of them is a one in both. The other ones in `i`, above the lowest one bit, are the same in both `i` and `i-1`, so they remain ones in `i & i-1`. The result of `i & i-1` is 1100 0000.
- 1100 0000 is 1100 1000 with the lowest set bit turned off.

Then the `% 3` is selecting which pole in Towers of Hanoi to use as the source. This is discussed in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209860/how-does-this-work-weird-towers-of-hanoi-solution).

Similarly `i | i-1` turns on all the low zeros in `i`, all the zeros up to the lowest one bit. Then `(i | i-1) + 1` adds one to that. The result is the same as adding one to the lowest one bit in `i`. That is, the result is `i + x`, where `x` is the lowest bit set in `i`. Using our example value:

- `i` is 1100 1000 and `i-1` is 1100 0111.
- `i | i-1` is 1100 1111.
- `(i | i-1) + 1` is 1101 0000, which equals 1100 1000 + 0000 1000.

And again, the `% 3` selects a pole.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A quick overview of bitwise operators:

Each operator takes the bits of both numbers and applies the operation to each bit of it.

### `&` Bitwise AND

True only if both bits are true.

Truth table:

```
A | B | A & B
-------------
0 | 0 | 0
1 | 0 | 0
0 | 1 | 0
1 | 1 | 1
```

### `|` Bitwise OR

True if either bit is true.

Truth table:

```
A | B | A | B
-------------
0 | 0 | 0
1 | 0 | 1
0 | 1 | 1
1 | 1 | 1
```

### `^` Bitwise XOR

True if only one bit is true.

Truth table:

```
A | B | A ^ B
-------------
0 | 0 | 0
1 | 0 | 1
0 | 1 | 1
1 | 1 | 0
```

### `~` Bitwise NOT

Inverts each bit. `1` -> `0`, `0` -> `1`. This is a unary operator.

Truth table:

```
A | ~A
------
0 | 1
1 | 0
```

In your case, if `i = 1`,
the expressions would be evaluated as:

```
source = (1 & 1-1) % 3;
target = ((1 | 1-1) + 1) % 3;
// =>
source = (1 & 0) % 3;
target = ((1 | 0) + 1) % 3;
// =>
source = 0 % 3;
target = (1 + 1) % 3;
// =>
source = 0;
target = 2 % 3;
// =>
source = 0;
target = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Good answer above, here is a high-level approach:

i == 1:
source: (1 & 0). Are both of these values true or >= 1? No they are not. So the overall result is 0, 0 % 3 = 0.

target: ((1 | 0) + 1) % 3. 
(1 | 0) evaluates to 1(true) since one of the two values on the sides of the | operator are 1, so now we have (1 + 1). so then it follows we have 2 % 3 = 2.

Source: 0, target: 2